# Inject node labels into Kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes

I am looking to deploy services to a Kubernetes cluster running over multiple zones and would like to be able to inject the region/zone labels into my pods using environment variables.

I have looked into the downward API however this only seems to allow you to inject labels/metadata from the pod/service and not from the node you are running the pod on.

If there is no way to inject the node labels another solution I thought about was having the container query the kubernetes/AWS API to fetch this information however that would mean adding quite a lot of complexity to my containers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I thought about was having the container query the kubernetes/AWS API to fetch this information however that would mean adding quite a lot of complexity to my containers.

This is currently the recommended approach for getting information not available in the downward API. To avoid the additional complexity in your containers, you could use a "sidecar" with a variation on [Tobias's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36690446/inject-node-labels-into-kubernetes-pod/36699927#36699927). The sidecar would be an additional container in the pod, which [connects to the kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/accessing-the-cluster/#accessing-the-api-from-a-pod), queries the information you're looking for (node labels), and writes the output to a shared volume. This could be implemented as an [init container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/), or a sidecar that continuously syncs with the API.

Comment: Yes. Recently I stumbled upon this issue. This is how I got it fixed for cassandra: https://gist.github.com/gmaslowski/117f3535173d733e007d0c6c83564888

Answer (score 5):

If you want to avoid having to grant Kubernetes API permissions to every pod that needs access to node labels, consider using a mutation webhook instead.

Example implementation with [kyverno](https://kyverno.io/) that adds topology labels to a pod when that pod is annotated with `copy-topology-labels-to-pod`:

```
apiVersion: kyverno.io/v1
kind: ClusterPolicy
metadata:
  name: copy-topology-labels-to-pod
spec:
  rules:
  - name: copy-topology-labels-to-pod
    match:
      any:
      - resources:
          kinds:
          - 'Pod'
    context:
    - name: topology_labels
      apiCall:
        urlPath: "/api/v1/nodes/{{request.object.spec.nodeName}}"
        jmesPath: "metadata.labels|items(@, 'key','value')[?pattern_match('topology.kubernetes.io/*', key)]|object_from_lists([].key, [].value)"
    preconditions:
    - all:
      - key: "{request.annotations.\"copy-topology-labels-to-pod\"}"
        operator: Equals 
        value: "true"
      - key: "{{request.object.spec.nodeName}}"
        operator: NotEquals
        value: ""
    mutate:
      patchStrategicMerge:
        metadata:
          labels: "{{ topology_labels }}"
        spec:
          containers:
          - env:
            - name: TOPOLOGY_REGION
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: "metadata.labels['topology.kubernetes.io/region']"
            - name: TOPOLOGY_ZONE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: "metadata.labels['topology.kubernetes.io/zone']"
```

Essentially your container doesn't need any API server permissions, as everything is performed for you on pod creation:

- when a pod has a nodeName it looks up node labels, keeps only the topology labels
- injects the topology labels onto the pod
- injects the label values as environment values into the pod with downward API

Comment: https://kyverno.io/policies/other/mutate-pod-binding/mutate-pod-binding/

Answer (score 2):

One option to achieve this is to store a custom file on each node that contains definitions of the environment variables that you want. Then you mount the folder containing the file into the container and source the file content as part of the startup of your container.

A similar approach for Kubernetes secrets is described here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/design/secrets.md#deferral-consuming-secrets-as-environment-variables

Comment: URL is not working. DO Always add a useful snippet from the URL.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, it's possible to access the labels via the kubernetes API.

I went ahead and made a fully working version to demonstrate this (including the RBAC needed): https://github.com/scottcrossen/kube-node-labels

With this example you can reference the node labels anywhere you would otherwise reference an environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

As a derivative of Tim St. Clair's answer, you may also consider writing out the pod metadata from within a [PostStart container hook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/). Go grab the metadata you want from [a well known URL](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata). Then write it out to k8s [via the API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/access-api-from-pod/). This has the advantage that it is a one-and-done execution. No need to keep a side-car running since region and zone info won't change.