# kubernetes on AWS get region name in pod

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes

I am running a kubernetes cluster on AWS-ec2 and I would like to have the pod (container) know during runtime which region it's running on, how can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few suggestions in this similar question: [Inject node labels into Kubernetes pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36690446/inject-node-labels-into-kubernetes-pod)

Options:

1. Sidecar container that queries the Kubernetes API
2. Place a data/configuration file on each node containing the region info

Comment: I checked them out, not my favourite option but it seems to be my only one.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at AWS [Instance Metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-data-retrieval):

> [...] instance metadata is available from your running instance, you
>   do not need to use the Amazon EC2 console or the AWS CLI. This can be
>   helpful when you're writing scripts to run from your instance

You can query the region of a given container querying the metadata from inside during runtime. Like this:

```
curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone
```

> [placement/availability-zone](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-data-categories): The Availability Zone in which the instance launched.

Answer (score 0):

Get the details of the nodes and you will be able to see the region of the nodes

```
kubectl get nodes -A
```