# how to inherit Node-Labels to Pod-Labels in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

Can I inherit node labels to pod labels?

i.e I want to have `zone` and `instance-type` labels from node to pods

Answer (score 8):

This feature is not yet supported.

[Here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/62078) is an open feature request on kubernetes.

Though there are [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36690446/inject-node-labels-into-kubernetes-pod) workarounds.

You can also refers [this](https://gmaslowski.com/kubernetes-node-label-to-pod/), where they make use of `initContainer` to get node label and assign it to pod label.

Hope this helps.