# kubernetes pod dynamic command line

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have a 3rd party docker container which takes arguments of the form:

```
docker run foo --arg1 val1 --arg2 val2
```

and I have run it as a pod in kubernetes as follows:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: foo
    image: foo
    args:
    -  --arg1
    - val1
    - --arg2
    - val2
```

This is good but I now need to have the two argument values dynamic. For example, val1 is the pod's name/id, and val2 is the *zone* (aws availability zone) of the node that the Pod is running on.

The only solution so I could think of is, to extend the container creating another image that runs a wrapper script, which queries for these two values and then pass them to the command line.

I am wondering if there's a more elegant solution than that. Let's say we can *obtain* these dynamic values in an *initContainer*. Now the question is how do we pass them on the command line of the main container.

PS: It looks like we can get the pod's name using Downward API. However, the Downward API does not expose node's label, for which there is an open [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/25957). So, for this question, let's think our parameters are arbitrary and are obtained dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be able to pass arguments as mentioned below.

HOSTNAME env will provide the detail for POD_NAME

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/

AWS Region specific details.

- [Inject node labels into Kubernetes pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36690446/inject-node-labels-into-kubernetes-pod)

**OR**

Run kubectl command on intialization and use node label with --show-labels to get region specific details based on assigned pod node.

Comment: Alright, this is what I am close to getting to work too right now - call the k8s api from an init container and put the result in a shared volume. This is still good amount of complexity but this is the best so far on this.