# Set node label to the pod environment variable

Tags: kubernetes

How to set Node label to Pod environment variable? I need to know the label `topology.kubernetes.io/zone` value inside the pod.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Downward API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/) currently does not support exposing node labels to pods/containers. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/40610) about that on GitHib, but it is unclear when it will be implemented if at all.

That leaves the only option to get node labels from Kubernetes API, just as `kubectl` does. It is not easy to implement, especially if you want labels as environment variables. I'll give you an example how it can be done with an `initContainer`, `curl`, and `jq` but if possible, I suggest you rather implement this in your application, for it will be easier and cleaner.

To make a request for labels you need permissions to do that. Therefore, the example below creates a service account with permissions to `get` (describe) nodes. Then, the script in the `initContainer` uses the service account to make a request and extract labels from `json`. The `test` container reads environment variables from the file and `echo`es one.

Example:

```yaml
# Create a service account
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: describe-nodes
  namespace: <insert-namespace-name-where-the-app-is>
---
# Create a cluster role that allowed to perform describe ("get") over ["nodes"]
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: describe-nodes
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["nodes"]
    verbs: ["get"]
---
# Associate the cluster role with the service account
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: describe-nodes
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: describe-nodes
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: describe-nodes
  namespace: <insert-namespace-name-where-the-app-is>
---
# Proof of concept pod
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: get-node-labels
spec:
  # Service account to get node labels from Kubernetes API
  serviceAccountName: describe-nodes

  # A volume to keep the extracted labels
  volumes:
    - name: node-info
      emptyDir: {}

  initContainers:
    # The container that extracts the labels
    - name: get-node-labels

      # The image needs 'curl' and 'jq' apps in it
      # I used curl image and run it as root to install 'jq'
      # during runtime
      # THIS IS A BAD PRACTICE UNSUITABLE FOR PRODUCTION
      # Make an image where both present.
      image: curlimages/curl
      # Remove securityContext if you have an image with both curl and jq
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 0

      # It'll put labels here
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /node
          name: node-info

      env:
        # pass node name to the environment
        - name: NODENAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.nodeName
        - name: APISERVER
          value: https://kubernetes.default.svc
        - name: SERVICEACCOUNT
          value: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
        - name: SCRIPT
          value: |
            set -eo pipefail

            # install jq; you don't need this line if the image has it
            apk add jq

            TOKEN=$(cat ${SERVICEACCOUNT}/token)
            CACERT=${SERVICEACCOUNT}/ca.crt

            # Get node labels into a json
            curl --cacert ${CACERT} \
                 --header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" \
                 -X GET ${APISERVER}/api/v1/nodes/${NODENAME} | jq .metadata.labels > /node/labels.json

            # Extract 'topology.kubernetes.io/zone' from json
            NODE_ZONE=$(jq '."topology.kubernetes.io/zone"' -r /node/labels.json)
            # and save it into a file in the format suitable for sourcing
            echo "export NODE_ZONE=${NODE_ZONE}" > /node/zone
      command: ["/bin/ash", "-c"]
      args:
        - 'echo "$$SCRIPT" > /tmp/script && ash /tmp/script'

  containers:
    # A container that needs the label value
    - name: test
      image: debian:buster
      command: ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
      # source ENV variable from file, echo NODE_ZONE, and keep running doing nothing
      args: ["source /node/zone && echo $$NODE_ZONE && cat /dev/stdout"]
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /node
          name: node-info
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [InitContainer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/#understanding-init-containers)

```
...
spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: node2pod
        image: <image-with-k8s-access>
        env:
        - name: NODE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.nodeName
       ...
```

Ref: [Node Label to Pod](https://gist.github.com/gmaslowski/117f3535173d733e007d0c6c83564888#file-cassandra-node2pod-yml-L36)

---

Edit Update

A similar Solution could be [Inject node labels into Kubernetes pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36690446/inject-node-labels-into-kubernetes-pod)