# Inject host's environment variable into K8s Pod

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables, kubernetes-helm

I would like to run a pod on one of my IoT devices.
Each one of those devices contains an environment variable I want this pod to use.
Is there any way to inject this env variable into the pod using build-in templating of `helm`/`kubectl`?
I was trying the following on my `deployment.yaml` file:

```
env: 
  - name: XXX
    value: $ENV_FROM_HOST
```

but when executing the pod and trying the get `XXX` value, I get the string `$ENV_FROM_HOST` instead of its value from the host:

```
$ echo $XXX
$ENV_FROM_HOST
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi. This environment variable will hold any sensitive information?

Comment: @EmidioNeto hi, absolutely not. using k3s secrets will be a huge overkill for my usecase.

Comment: Where is the environment variable normally set?  Does it matter which node the pod is actually running on?

Comment: I set this env using `ansible` over all of my nodes. so no, it doesn't matter, cause every pod is going to have this env on its host.

Comment: My question is more, hosts don't have environment variables, processes do.  So are you trying to get an environment variable from a specific process, or a shell dotfile like `/etc/profile`, or some other source?  Can you inject it into a Kubernetes-native store like a ConfigMap?  If you configure a Pod with a variable value but it gets scheduled on a node with a different value, does it matter to your processing?

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm trying to get an environment variable from /etc/environment.  My environment variable is similar to the `HOST_NAME` idea (let's call it `LOCATION_NAME` - a variable that identifies the device's location.) - I want my pod to have its location from its host.  As I'm managing my hosts (self-hosted), I can guarantee that every host will have the *right value* for the environment variable. Now it is only about injecting this `LOCATION_NAME` into my pod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to directly pass the host's env vars to the pods. I often do that by creating a ConfigMap.

1. Create a ConfigMap with `from-lireral` option:

   ```
   kubectl create configmap testcm --from-literal=hostname=$HOSTNAME
   ```
2. Refer to that in the Pod's manifest:

   ```yaml
   - name: TEST
     valueFrom:
       configMapKeyRef:
         name: testcm
         key: hostname
   ```

This will inject the host's $HOSTNAME into the Pod's $TEST.

If it's sensitive information, you can use Secrets instead of using ConfigMap.

Comment: It works on the command line but how do we achieve that in the ConfigMap manifest file?

Answer (score 0):

Speaking about Kubernetes, one of the assumption is that pod is only [sharing resources between containers in the pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/):

> A  *Pod*  (as in a pod of whales or pea pod) is a group of one or more  [containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/), with shared storage and network resources, and a specification for how to run the containers. A Pod's contents are always co-located and co-scheduled, and run in a shared context.

That means a pod is isolated from the host that is running on (node), so you can't just straight read an environment variable from the node as you want.

However, some workarounds are coming to my mind.

If the environment variable is the same for all nodes:

- If you are using CI/CD, then you can implement the following code.
  In deployment definition - `deployment.yaml`

  ```yaml
  env: 
    - name: XXX
      value: ENV_TO_CHANGE
  ```

  The command:

  ```
  sed "s/ENV_TO_CHANGE/{YOUR_VALUE}/g" deployment.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
  ```

  It won't edit existing file; it will output the edited `deployment.yaml` file and it will pipe to `kubectl apply` command

If the environment variables is different for each node:

- Set your environment variables as node labels and then inject them into pods - some solutions are presented in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36690446/inject-node-labels-into-kubernetes-pod).
- (NOT RECOMMENDED) - save an environment variable on the node as the file in a specific directory, then read this on the pod using [`hostPath`  volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath). Keep in mind that `hostPath` presents many security risks and it's better to avoid it.